# Compute percentage on array of objects (dynamic) by key

Tags: javascript

I have below array of object in javascript. The size of the array might vary if any new `status` key arrived.

```js
[
    {'status':'init','count':1000},
    {'status':'start','count':2500},
    {'status':'done','count':1500}
]
```

Need to get the output in below format. Basically the percentage across all objects within the array by the key.

```js
[
    {'status':'init','percentage':20},
    {'status':'start','percentage':50},
    {'status':'done','percentage':30}
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two steps: First loop over the elements and add up all the counts to get a total. Then loop over the elements, calculate the percentarge, and replace the `count` property with the `percentage` property.

Comment: status can only be added? or you can modify/delete existing status? are always positive/integer numbers? how much statuses can you have? whats the max value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the sum of all counts and generate new objects with the percentage value.

```js
var data = [{ status: 'init', count: 1000 }, { status: 'start', count: 2500 }, { status: 'done', count: 1500 }],
    sum = data.reduce((s, { count }) => s + count, 0),
    result = data.map(({ status, count }) => ({ status, percentage: count * 100 / sum }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const myArr = [
   {'status':'init','count':1000},
   {'status':'start','count':2500},
   {'status':'done','count':1500}
]

const total = myArr.reduce((a,i)=> a + i.count ,0)

const final = myArr.map(e=> ({...e, percentage: e.count * 100 / total})
```